# Add to exisiting Database instance from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

```
        Private BookingDB db = new BookingDB();
        Private MonthDb mdb = new MonthDB();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            String date = (booking.Start_Date).ToString();

            var check = from b in mdb.months
                        where b.BookedDays.Contains(date)
                        select b;

            if (check != null)
            {
                return View(booking);
            }
            else
            {
                booking.Reservation_Owner = User.Identity.Name;

                //Add booking.Start_Date to mdb.Entry(check).BookedDays

                mdb.SaveChanges();
                db.bookings.Add(booking);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

I've got this code that on creation of a new booking, will check that no exisiting bookings have already been made on or around that specific day.
if the day to be booked is not already been booked (ie exists under BookedDays in mdb.months) then i wish to add the Start_Date of the booking, to the BookedDays string in the mdb.months database (the mdb.month database is just a list of the 12 months)

at first i tried using mdb.Entry() to add to that specific month instance, however i cannot get it to work.

the error is:

> the model does not have a definition for BookedDays

what do?

Comment: Did you get any errors? have you attched the debugger and checked everything? what do you mean by *however i cannot get it to work*?

Comment: mdb.Entry(check.BookedDays) = booking.Start_Date; 
thats is what i'm trying todo, the error is that the model does not have a definition for BookedDays

Answer (score 0):

Your checking that check is null

```
if (check != null)
{
     return View(booking);
}
else
{
```

and then using check anyway:

```
check.BookedDays
```

check is null and therefore does not contain any `BookedDays`. I'm guessing your null check is the wrong way around and should be

```
if (check == null)
{
     return View(booking);
}
else
{
```

That said your problem is not well explained so I'm not sure.